# Dhtmlxwindow attachURL issue

Tags: dhtmlx

I have created a dhtmlxwindow object and loaded a jsp page using attachURL.

dhxwindow.attachURL('myPage.jsp');

and in myPage.jsp ,
i have created a layout object.

```
var mylayout = new dhtmlxLayoutObject(document.body, '3u');
toolbar = mylayout.cells('a').attachToolbar();
toolbar.addButton("Validate", 0, "", "images/queryValidation24.png", "images/queryValidation24.png");
toolbar.addButton("Preview", 1, "", "images/previewBtn24.png", "images/previewBtn24.png");
toolbar.setAlign('right');
```

//and i have other dhtmlxcomponents in other cells

Problem is i am unable to view the toolbar.

What will be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use correct syntax as CAPITAL letters:
var mylayout = new dhtml**X**LayoutObject(document.body, '3**U**');

Main page:

```
dhxWins = new dhtmlXWindows();
dhxWins.enableAutoViewport(false);
dhxWins.attachViewportTo(document.body);
dhxWins.setImagePath("../dhtmlxWindows/codebase/imgs/");
w1 = dhxWins.createWindow("w1", 100, 100, 500, 500);
w1.attachURL("layout_toolbar_test.html");
```

Attached page:

```
var mylayout = new dhtmlXLayoutObject(document.body, '3U');
toolbar = mylayout.cells('a').attachToolbar();
toolbar.addButton("Validate", 0, "", "images/queryValidation24.png", "images/queryValidation24.png");
toolbar.addButton("Preview", 1, "", "images/previewBtn24.png", "images/previewBtn24.png");
toolbar.setAlign('right');
```

Result (sorry, haven't your image files):
[image]